# How to use request data Buffer in Next.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, buffer

Framework : Next.JS

I have to upload image to Next.JS server and after that Image will get uploaded to Amazon AWS S3 bucket. For uploading image to S3 we have to read it into Buffer and store. I am uploading image from Next.JS frontend to Next.JS Server.
**Http Request image :**
[image]

**Http Request payload :**

[image]

**file** contains the Array of files that need to be uploaded on server.

On Next.JS i am able to get request body data that is in Buffer form . If i convert it into the string it shows like this :

[image]

**Code :**

```
import { BufferEncoding, IncomingForm } from "formidable"
import {serialize, deserialize} from "v8";
//import { Buffer } from 'node:buffer';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        var data = "";
        req.on('data', chunk => {
            try{
                //console.log("To JSON : ",chunk.toJSON())
                //console.log("To String : ",chunk.toString())
                //console.log(chunk.isEncoding())
                data += chunk;
            }catch(e){
                console.log("Data : ",e)
            }
        });
        req.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data');
            console.log("\nSerialize : ",serialize(data))
            console.log("\nData string : ",data.toString())
            res.status(200).json({ data: null, error: "Success" });
        })
        
        //res.status(200).json({ data: null, error: "Success1" });
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Error message : ",e)
        res.status(400).json({ data: null, error: "Invalid Method" });
        return;
    }
}
export default handler;

export const config = {
    api: {
      bodyParser: false, // Disallow body parsing, consume as stream
    },
}
```

Question :

**How can i convert request payload buffer into usable format(like JSON or anything) for reading files that is sent in request ?**

Note :

I want to avoid module like multer.

I want to upload large image files and after that large video files.